# How to determine what file is scheduled to run with SchTasks.exe in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

For a given task I need to determine what file it is trying to run with a batch code. Currently I use `schtasks /query /TN ITCMD-CHAT-NOTIF | find "Ready"` to determine if the task is active, but I see no way to determine what file it is executing. Is it possible?

Comment: If you add `/v` to the run string (`schtasks /query /v /TN ITCMD-CHAT-NOTIF`), one of the fields contains the schedule string, though it is limited to 50 characters.

Comment: Add a /v and remove the pipe with _find_ and instead pipe it to a file, then please click `edit` above and add the result, so we can see more of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

To find the full path of the file being run, you can use the `/XML` switch and `FIND "<Command>"`.

This gives you the XML file you would get if you exported the task, so you can't get both the Status and the Command fields using this command. Instead, you could create a batch file that will run both commands.

**task_status.bat:**

```
schtasks /query /TN %1 | find "Ready"
schtasks /query /TN %1 /XML | find "<Command>"
```

You can then run `task_status.bat ITCMD-CHAT-NOTIF` to get both fields of the task.